# openmp fortran reduction and critical not working for array

Tags: arrays, fortran, openmp

I am currently trying to get a fortran FE (finite element) code to work with openmp. I have a loop over all elements, `ie` that I want to work in parallel. Here is a simplified part of the code that is not working

```
     !$omp parallel do default(none) shared(nelm,A,res,enod) private(ie,Fe,B,edof)     
    do ie=1,nelm 
       call calcB(B,A(:,ie))
       call calcFe(Fe,B)
       write(*,*) Fe !writes Fe=40d0, this is correct

        call getEdof(edof,enod(:,ie))
        !$OMP CRITICAL      
        res(edof)=res(edof)+fe
        !$OMP END CRITICAL 
        enddo 
!$omp end parallel do
```

The purpose of the code is to calculate a force `Fe` and then adding it to `res` at `edof`. The force is calculated with `calcFe`, and the calculated force is correct, but the resulting `res` is incorrect after the loop.

If I replace `calcFe` with simply `Fe=40d0` then add it to `res` the result is correct after the loop

```
     !$omp parallel do default(none) shared(nelm,A,res,enod) private(ie,Fe,B,edof)


    do ie=1,nelm 
       call calcB(B,A(:,ie))

       Fe=40d0

        call getEdof(edof,enod(:,ie))
        !$OMP CRITICAL      
        res(edof)=res(edof)+fe
        !$OMP END CRITICAL 
        enddo 
!$omp end parallel do
```

What causes this error?  In both cases `Fe=40d0` is declared `private` but  only one of them gives the correct result. Instead of using `!$ CRITICAL` I could use `reduction` but it gives the same error. In the program  several large and sparse matrices are also used but the are passive/ not used during the loop. My supervisor has had problems with using openmp and sparse matrices before and suspects that they are using the same memory. If the error is not apparent what debugger is best to use? Im a novice to both fortran ,openmp and programing in general.
Im using `ifort` to compile and my OS is ubuntu.

EDIT: Added simplified code that you can run, although this code works
In the code there are two loops, on parallel and one serial, to they should give the same result, `res` and `res2`

```
program main

use omp_lib

implicit none

integer :: ie, nelm,enod(4,50*50),edof(12),i,j,k
double precision ::B(12,8),fe(12),A(12,12,2500),res(2601*3),res2(2601*3),finish,start

  !creates  enod
  i=1
  do j=1,50
    ie=j
    do k=1,50
       nelm=k
       enod(:,i)=(/ 51*(nelm-1)+1+ie-1, 51*(nelm-1)+1+ie, 51*(nelm)+1+ie-1, 51*(nelm)+1+ie /)
        i=i+1
    end do
  end do

   A=1d0
   res2=0d0
   nelm=2500   
   start=omp_get_wtime()          
   !$omp parallel do default(none) shared(nelm,A,enod) private(ie,fe,edof,B) reduction(+:res2)
      do ie=1,nelm
            call calcB(B,A(:,:,ie))
          call calcFe(fe,B) !the calculated fe is always 2304
          !can write fe=2304 to get correct result with real code
          call getEdof(edof,enod(:,ie))
          res2(edof)=res2(edof)+fe
      end do
   !$omp end parallel do
   finish=omp_get_wtime()
    write(*,*) 'time: ', finish-start

   res=0d0
   nelm=2500             
   start=omp_get_wtime()
      do ie=1,nelm
            call calcB(B,A(:,:,ie))
          call calcFe(fe,B)
          call getEdof(edof,enod(:,ie))
          res(edof)=res(edof)+fe
      end do
        finish=omp_get_wtime()
    write(*,*) 'time: ', finish-start
    write(*,*) 'difference: ',sum(res2-res) 
    write(*,*) sum(res2)

stop

end program main

subroutine calcB(B,A)
double precision ::B(12,8),A(12,12),C(12)
integer          ::gp
  C=1d0
  do gp=1,8
    B(:,gp)=matmul(A,C)
  end do
end subroutine calcB


subroutine calcFe(fe,B)
double precision  ::fe(12),B(12,8),D(12,12)
integer           ::gp
  fe=0d0
  D=2d0

  do gp=1,8
    fe=fe+matmul(D,B(:,gp))
  end do


end subroutine calcFe


subroutine getEdof(edof,enod)
    implicit none
    integer,intent(in) :: enod(4)
    integer,intent(out):: edof(12)
    edof=0
    edof(1:3)  =(/ enod(1)*3-2, enod(1)*3-1, enod(1)*3 /)
    edof(4:6)  =(/ enod(2)*3-2, enod(2)*3-1, enod(2)*3 /)
    edof(7:9)  =(/ enod(3)*3-2, enod(3)*3-1, enod(3)*3 /)
    edof(10:12)=(/ enod(4)*3-2, enod(4)*3-1, enod(4)*3 /)

end subroutine getedof
```

And the make file

```
    FF = ifort -O3 -openmp
OBJ1  = main.f90
ls: $(FORT_OBJS)
    $(FF) -o exec $(OBJ1)
```

Unfortunately this piece of code works, so i'm unable to replicate the error. `res2` and `res` are calculated in serial and parallel. In my real program I have put all values to `1d0` in order to get a constant `fe`. The calulated fe is correct, if I add a `write(*,*) fe` after `calcFe` I see that the values are correct. I then add these values to `res2` and compare them with the serial `res`. They are then different by a large margin, so there is no numerical roundoff error. If I simply declare `fe=2304` in my main program I get the correct answer even though `fe` already is 2304 when write is used.

In the my real program all the subroutines are in different modules, do I need to take any special care because of this?
Also in one of the modules some global variables are used, they are read only but since they are not declared in the subroutine they are not automaticly made private? This should be no issue since I put all variables used to to calulate `fe` to a constant, the global variables are not used directly to calculate `fe`

Comment: Use reduction here, critical is a bad idea in this case.

Comment: Try to create a fully compilable self-contained example we can compile and run. Explain which value is the wrong result and which result do you expect.

Comment: I am afraid we can't do anything without a piece of code which *reproduces* the error.  Often you find the problem yourself when you try to isolate a small working example. *"since they are not declared in the subroutine they are not automaticly made private?"* ... no, but if they are not changed they can remain shared, that is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, it started working when I added `-openmp` to the makefile for my modules. Apparently the modules needs to be compiled with `-openmp` and not just the main file.